# How to select and run macro macro in one on click function using Javascript?

Tags: visualforce, macros

How to select and run macro macro in one on click function using Javascript? i am using these two values "sforce.console.selectMacro(id); and sforce.console.runSelectedMacro(id);" with two buttons and two onclick functions.
i need to call those functions in one onclick function with one button in visualforce page. can anybody help me onthis.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the 2 macros to be executed sequentially, call the second one from the callback in first runSelectedMacro.

Its easier if youre working with Case feed: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide_component_interactions.htm